# Retrieve Data from MySQL server within a time interval

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I've a table called `graphs` and it has my fields like:

`id, name, channel, created..` etc. `created` field is `DATETIME`.

Now, I want to retrieve data with `one minute` time interval. That is, date difference with current time and `created` field will be `one minute`.

Here `created` field date format is: `Y-m-d h:i:s`.

What is the solution? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) <= created;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: `CURDATE()` return `Y-m-d` format, but my `created` field is `Y-m-d h:i:s` format. does your solution work with that? `:)`

Answer (score 0):

One possible query might be:

```
SELECT * FROM graphs WHERE  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`created`) <= 60)
```

Check [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)